# How to get the full view of Apache Lucene indexed data table like "select * from Table_Name"?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I do need check the data indexed with Apache lucene (v3.6.1). How to get the full view of Lucene index?
Have are there any program (like MySQL GUI or console) for view index or code samples of doing it with the Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) is typically the best way to view the data in an index.  It gives you a lot of tools for viewing documents and indexed terms, and running queries against it.

From the Java API, you can get all documents simply by using a [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html).